# [php]How to fetch the specific header from a block of headers with the same filed name?

Tags: php, http

I want to get the value of sid from the last two set-cookie header after the request was posted.

`sid=20076232_f83094c0b2cd89e6e2ee92cdc23eb36c;` which is what I need.

```
function SendRequest($url, $method, $data, $headers) {
$context = stream_context_create(array
(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => $method,
        'header' => $headers,
        //'content' => http_build_query($data)
        'content' => $data
    )
));

$response_body = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
//var_dump($http_response_header);
return array(
    'headers' => $http_response_header, 
    'body' => $response_body
);
```

}

`get_headers()` function returns an array but not working to access it by index number. sometime it is random

The response headers look like this

```
HostName: *.*.2.111
Set-Cookie: nickname=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/;

Set-Cookie: sid=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/;

Set-Cookie: nickname=%25E4%25B8%2580%25E8%2591%2589%25E9%2580%2599%25E5%25A4%25A9; expires=Mon, 22-Oct-2018 13:44:14 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/

Set-Cookie: sid=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/

Set-Cookie: sid=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; 

Set-Cookie: nickname=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; 

Set-Cookie: nickname=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/

Set-Cookie: sid=20076232_f83094c0b2cd89e6e2ee92cdc23eb36c; expires=Mon, 22-Oct-2018 13:44:14 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.38-pl0-gentoo
```

Comment: Please show us your attempts with an explanation of what happens and we can help you from there.

Comment: There's also a problem with your header array. sid and nickname is set 4 times. I think you might have another problem in your code as well, however without any code we will not be able to solve your problem.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I need to make a server-to-server api call . This api is provided by third-party and I can't control it how to respond to the post request. I want to get the specific header set-cookie with the value of sid from the block of duplicate headers named set-cookie after post request from my own server. I edited my question description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply filter the output of [`get_headers`](http://php.net/get_headers) using [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep):

```
#                        ↓↓ hex ↓↓
$sids = preg_grep("/sid=([\d_a-f]+);/", $headers);
```

And then use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) to extract the last valid id. Or simply implode the headers into one text blob, and extract the first match (seeing that there's only one).